# Android Actionbar change menus position

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to use android-support-v7-appcompat and my problem change menus position to right of actionbar

As you can see on the attached picture I wanna change the position of menu in action bar with custom view which is inflate of a custom layout.. hope to understand what I'm say

[image: Change Positions]

Comment: what exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: Please specify the details so that we can help. This question is very vague.

Comment: As you can see on the attached picture I wanna change the position of menu in action bar with custom view which is inflate of a custom layout.. hope to understand what I'm say..
[link](http://www.xum.ir/images/2014/05/28/device-2014-05-25-171041.png)

Comment: Edit the question instead of adding detail in comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To arrange menus order change this

```
 android:orderInCategory="100"
```

Answer (score 2):

The menu Items that are created in onCreateOptionsMenu are always the right most items. I think it is not possible to have a custom view to the right of your menu.